# Polars get the diff value of a monotonically increasing values with erratic data

Tags: python-polars

I have a data from observations taken every 1 minute. The observation data values are always increasing. Sometimes there are erratic data where `data[n] < data[n-1]`.

Example:

```
pl.DataFrame(dict(
  time= ['10:00', '10:01', '10:02', '10:03', '10:04', '10:05', '10:06'],
  value=[  1000 ,     10 ,     22 ,      22 ,     50 ,   1100 ,     60 ]
))
```

I want to get the data per minute and smooth over the invalid values. So in this case when we see `10` after `1000`, we set `1000` to `0` and we split the difference, so `5` for `10:00`and `5` for `10:01`.

For the previous dataframe, the result should be `5, 5, 12, 0, 28, 5, 5`.

How can we express this in polars?

This expression seems to work except that it misses the first two values

```
df.with_columns(
  pl.when(pl.col('value').shift(-1) < pl.col('value'))
    .then(0)
    .otherwise(pl.col('value'))
    .alias('value_fixed')
).with_columns(
  pl.when(pl.col('value_fixed') == 0)
    .then((pl.col('value_fixed').shift() + pl.col('value_fixed').shift(-1)) / 2)
    .otherwise(pl.col('value_fixed'))
    .alias('value_fixed_avg')
).with_columns(
    pl.col('value_fixed_avg').diff()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting those `null`s potentially at the start because when the first value is set to 0, the `shift` to the left is going OOB (that is, gives a `null` in that spot). `diff` also is automatically `null` on the first value for its default argument.

A couple of `fill_null`s for these edge cases seems to solve it:

```
...
.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("value_fixed") == 0)
    .then(
        (
            pl.col("value_fixed").shift().fill_null(pl.col("value_fixed").first())
            + pl.col("value_fixed").shift(-1)
        )
        / 2
    )
    .otherwise(pl.col("value_fixed"))
    .alias("value_fixed_avg")
).with_columns(
    pl.col("value_fixed_avg").diff().fill_null(pl.col("value_fixed_avg").first())
)
```

Comment: Thanks, fill_null might do it, although it'd be better if there is a fill_value parameter for shift like in pandas.

Comment: @char101 It has its own function in polars, [`.shift_and_fill`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.shift_and_fill.html#polars-expr-shift-and-fill)

Comment: @jqurious Thanks, you are right, I forgot that shift_and_fill exists. Now if only there is also diff_and_fill.

Comment: I haven't used `shift_and_fill` before, even better!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [`.interpolate`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.interpolate.html#polars.Expr.interpolate) could be of use here.

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.when((pl.col("value") < pl.col("value").shift()).shift(-1))
     .then(None)
     .otherwise(pl.col("value"))
     .interpolate()
     .fill_null(pl.col("value").shift(-1) / 2)
     .diff()
     .backward_fill()
)
```

```
shape: (7, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬─────────┐
│ time  ┆ value ┆ literal │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---     │
│ str   ┆ i64   ┆ f64     │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═════════╡
│ 10:00 ┆ 1000  ┆ 5.0     │
│ 10:01 ┆ 10    ┆ 5.0     │
│ 10:02 ┆ 22    ┆ 12.0    │
│ 10:03 ┆ 22    ┆ 0.0     │
│ 10:04 ┆ 50    ┆ 28.0    │
│ 10:05 ┆ 1100  ┆ 5.0     │
│ 10:06 ┆ 60    ┆ 5.0     │
└───────┴───────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: This looks even better because it can be done in one pass.